# Reading the output of a variable

Tags: variables, powershell, active-directory

Alright, So I'm writing a code for mass user creation in Active Directory. The code has to automatically create the user names as well.

```
Import-Csv C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Test\Test.csv |  % {
$Firstname = $_.Firstname
$MiddleIntial = $_.MiddleIntial
$Lastname = $_.Lastname
$Username = $Firstname.substring(0,1).ToLower()+$MiddleIntial.ToLower()+$Lastname.ToLower()
$testname = (Get-ADUser $Username)
if($testname - $Error){
Write-Host $Username
}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is verify that the user name is unique before the code continues to the actual creation part.

Answer (score 0):

After running `Get-ADUser`, you can test the value of `$?` to see if the last statement executed successfully:

```
$testname = Get-ADUser -Filter "samaccountname -eq '$UserName'"
if(-not $?){
    # No users with samaccountname $UserName found, go ahead
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be giving me the desired result, it appears to be skipping `if(-not $?){
    # No users with samaccountname $UserName found, go ahead
}`

Comment: $? will only be false if the last command failed. If Get-ADUser succeeded to query AD but no users were found, $? is still true.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function to test for available usernames and run it each time I want to test if a username is available.

The function could look something like this:

```
function Test-UsernameAvailable
{
    param($UserName)
    $Users = @(Get-ADUser -ldapFilter "(sAMAccountName=$UserName)" -ErrorAction Stop)
    if($Users.Count -eq 0)
    {
        return $true
    }
    else
    {
        return $false
    }
}
```

Enclusing Get-ADUser in @() forces the result to be an array which means it will always have a property called count. This way I can test if count is 0, which means the name is available.

Later on I can call my function in an if-statement to check if a username is available, for example:

```
if(Test-UsernameAvailable -Name $Username)
{
    #Username is available
}
else
{
    #Username is not available
}
```